# Referencing specific key value in JSON output

Tags: python, json, for-loop

I have a JSON output that returns a lot of data, but I am only concerned with one piece of it. A part of my output is below:

```
data = {'vulnerabilities': {'critical': 3,
                            'exploits': 1,
                            'malwareKits': 0,
                            'moderate': 9,
                            'severe': 29,
                            'total': 41}}
```

I would like to only reference `'critical'` so that my output will have the number of criticals in there.

Code tried:

```
for element in data['vulnerabilities']:
    if element == ['critical']:
       print(element)
```

Comment: forgive me if i'm misunderstanding, but what's wrong with `print(data['vulnerabilities']['critical'])`?

Comment: @Klaycon this works! can't believe i didn't think of this. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a lot of issues with your code.

```
for element in data['vulnerabilities']:
```

Here I see, you are accessing data['vulnerabilities'], which returns a dict itself. So when you are iterating over it, by default, python iterates over the keys.

Here

```
element == 'critical'
```

is correct and not

```
if element == ['critical']:
```

Here I assume you want to print the value of the key, as I mentioned above, the element is  one of the keys in dict so you should iterate over its items like below.

```
for key, value in data['vulnerabilities'].items():
    if key == 'critical':
       print(value)
```

Comment: my apologies, still trying to learn this stuff. appreciate your help!

Comment: yes, perfectly fine. and there is no need to apologize.. cheers ...